# Find spikes in data

Tags: statistics, average, data-analysis

I have some datasets and I need to find spikes in them. Imagine the data looks like trading data. If the spike is big enough, I need to log it, otherwise, proceed in the analysis.

I tried with a moving average approach, but cannot detect all of them. Is there a better way?

Also, I would like to know if there is a robust approach to calculating the baseline, so I can filter it out.

Comment: You need a precise definition of *spike*, to begin with.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.nucleics.com/images/site_images/large-spike-raw.gif I cannot really find a proper definition, as the size of it varies between dataset and dataset.